# Ion-row renders off screen

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a simple view:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid *ngIf="loaded">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>Stuff</ion-col>
      <ion-col>Stuff</ion-col>
      <ion-col>Stuff</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
<ion-content>
```

but the `<ion-row>` element renders offscreen due to a -15px margin applied to the left and right.  **Is this the intended behavior?**

```
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ion col or ion-row  has default padding and margin, so if you don't want to use then add tag no-margin and no-padding   default margin and padding will be removed

Comment: But in the examples, it doesn't seem as though it should render that way.  Or `ion-col` should counter the padding/margin so that it starts at 0.  Seems odd that the intended behavior would be to render offscreen

Comment: its not intended behavior. ion-grid has 5 padding by default and same in col but not in row